# dateadd in the where clause - how can I avoid a full scan in this particular situation?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance, index, sql-server-2016, execution-plan

I have the following query:

```
SELECT      u.userId,
            app.applicationId
FROM        app.application                 AS app
INNER JOIN  app.applicant                   AS ap   
            ON ap.applicantId = app.applicantId
INNER JOIN  usr.[user]                      AS u    
            ON u.userId = ap.userId
LEFT JOIN   msg.emailTemplateSent           AS t    
            ON t.toUserId = u.userId 
           AND t.emailTemplateName = 'v4_before_sixWeek_latestFlight_reminder'

WHERE       Convert(Date, GETUTCDATE())  = 
            DATEADD(week,-6,Convert(Date, app.flightDateLatest ))

AND         t.emailEventId IS NULL

ORDER BY    app.applicationId ASC
```

Please pay attention to the first line of the where clause again:

```
Convert(Date, GETUTCDATE())  = DATEADD(week,-6,Convert(Date, app.flightDateLatest ))
```

Could I change this in a way that my index can get used? The index actually get used, but it is a full scan.

[image]

It can also be seen here:

[image]

This is my index definition:

```
USE [APCore];
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX i_flightDateLatest  
ON [app].[application] ( flightDateLatest  ASC  )  
INCLUDE ( [applicantId] , [applicationId] , [programID])  
WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        FILLFACTOR = 100  , 
        SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , 
        ONLINE = OFF, 
--DROP_EXISTING = ON, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
       STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
       DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE, 
       ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
       ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) 
ON [NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES]
```

[This is the full execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJxAWTZmq).

Unfortunately I cannot change the column called `flightDateLatest` from datetime to date to [avoid convertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203984/22336)

Other than creating a [computed column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/116348/22336) or change the schema, is there anything else that can be done to avoid reading the [full table\index scan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177337/22336) in this situation?

**Update:**

After the accepted answer, changed the query accordingly and now the index is used in a *seek* operation as you can see on the picture below.

Please note the 94% of cost of the original query to the 6% improved query:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add 6 weeks to your getutc...

and then test that particular day (flightDateLatest)  to be greater or equal to `DATEADD(week,6,Convert(Date, GETUTCDATE()))`

and less then next day `DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(week,6,Convert(Date, GETUTCDATE())))`

```
SELECT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT CAST('20220511 15:14:52.050' AS DATETIME) as flightDateLatest union all
    SELECT CAST('20220512' AS DATETIME) 
) as app
WHERE   
    app.flightDateLatest >= DATEADD(week,6,Convert(Date, GETUTCDATE()))
    AND 
    app.flightDateLatest < DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(week,6,Convert(Date, GETUTCDATE())))
```

with output:

```
flightDateLatest
2022-05-11 15:14:52.050
```

Answer (score 2):

### computed

Another potential solution is adding a computed column to your table and indexing that instead, but that's probably overkill here. It makes more sense in situations when your date math is based on two columns.

```
ALTER TABLE       
    app.application
ADD 
    flightDateLatestComputed AS 
        DATEADD
        (
            WEEK,
            -6,
            CONVERT
            (
                date, 
                flightDateLatest,
                112
            )
        );
```